Infinite navigation and BottomNavigationBar management with go_router
I'm having a problem managing my routes under Flutter using go_router. I would like my routes to work like this:
Home
├─ post/:id
          └─ user/:id
                     ├─ post/:id
                     │         └─ […]
                     └─ feedcollectionuser/:id
                                             └─ post/:id
                                                       └─ […]
Feed
├─ post/:id
          └─ user/:id
                     ├─ post/:id
                     │         └─ […]
                     └─ feedcollectionuser/:id
                                             └─ post/:id
                                                       └─ […]

It creates an infinite loop in my navigation : I want to keep it, and keep the history of my navigation.
For example, from a post, I can navigate to a user (user1), then on this user1, I can access a post from user2, and so on. It's an endless loop.
I noticed that I could handle this loop while keeping the history of my navigation by putting some routes outside my ShellRoute, but this poses another problem: I lose my BottomNavigationBar, which is crucial for my application.
Current code:

GoRouter createRouter(BuildContext context) {
  final authBloc = context.read<AuthBloc>();

  final goRouter = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: <RouteBase>[

      // User Profile
      GoRoute(
        path: '/user/:userId',
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          // Your logic here
        },
      ),

      // Post
      GoRoute(
        path: '/post/:postId',
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          // Your logic here
        },
      ),

      // StatefulShellBranch
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {
          return ScaffoldWithNavBar(
            currentLocation: state.uri.toString(),
            navigationShell: navigationShell,
            userIdFromAuth: authBloc.state.user!.uid,
            appBar: null,
          );
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[

          // Home
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/home',
                pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  // Your logic here
                },
                routes: [
                  // Nested routes
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),

          // Feed
          StatefulShellBranch(
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: '/feed',
                pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  // Your logic here
                },
                routes: [
                  // Nested routes
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  return goRouter;
}

Do you have any suggestions on how to manage navigation smoothly while keeping the BottomNavigationBar?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I've found the beginnings of a solution, which is to put the user and post routes in the statefulshellbranch: (/home/post/:postId - /home/user/:userId ...)
But this complicates the push paths, and the reuse of my widgets (I can elaborate if needed).

Which go_router method are you using to move from one screen to another? If you are using push or pushNamed, you could try with go / goNamed to avoid the loop.

so whats your desired route or like what conditions you want to implement ?

if you don't want backward navigation use go/goNamed and If you want backward navigation use push/pushNamed.

I use GoRouter.of(context).push, because I need to keep the history of my stack so I can go back.
With my current code it's working for the route but when I push to the Post, I lost my ScaffoldWithNavBar, wich I want to keep
